# How to update many records in mondodb in python?

Tags: python, django, database, mongodb, pymongo

I want to update records in mongodb using python:
I am using this code it does the job. However the length of **data** is around one million and it takes a lot of time.

```
new_data = []
for x in data:
    if collection.find({'ptr_id':x["ptr_id"]}).count() < 0 :
        new_data += [x]
    else:
        bulkop.find({'ptr_id':x["ptr_id"]}).update({ "$set": x })
try:
    result = bulkop.execute()
except:
    ...
```

How can I run this faster. FYI **collection.find({'ptr_id':x["ptr_id"]}).count()** will always be **0** or **1**. A different approach can also he helpful

Comment: Is there not a way you can describe this as a mongo query?  It's always more efficient to let the server do the work.

Comment: No, I don't think so, It can work that way. My main concern is that can I do something else  to avoid/minimise the for loop.   Like using **update_many**

Comment: If you have a million elements in `data` you are performing `collection.find` a million times - that is not very efficient.